# Accessing variables from different scripts in a lua_State

Tags: c++, lua, scripting

I have the following problem:
I am building a small (a toy really) game platform using C++ and lua (and well, SDL too).
I can't seem to find out how to use variables inside a lua script that are defined in another lua script in the same working directory.
I tried loading all scripts into a single lua_State, but that did not work.
For example:

I have a file `code.lua` and another one `player.lua` (something like a class containing variables and functions for a player character). I run the file `code.lua` inside my C++ program (using `luaL_dofile`) but I also need that file to be able to access variables in `player.lua` and modify them too.

Using `require` is apparently not supported when not using lua standalone. 
I am using Lua 5.3, so I guess `module()` doesn't work either. (I am very new to lua, excuse me if all of this is in fact trivial or just not the right way of doing things). Thanks for any help!

Comment: "*Using `require` is apparently not supported when not using lua standalone.*" Nonsense. There's nothing about `require` that needs the Lua executable.

Comment: @NicolBolas I completely believe you, however using a `require` causes my script to not run at all, which is why I had that thought.

Comment: Actually running the script on the command line with `lua code.lua` using `require` works and I can access the variable in the other file, but not when running the script from inside the C++ program. I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you actually loading the stdlib? (`#include <lualib.h>` , [`luaL_openlibs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_openlibs)`( L )`) If you don't there's no `require`, which would explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: @nobody yes, unfortunately that's not the problem.

Comment: Try adding a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question if you still want this solved. At present, there's not enough information to do anything but guess.

Comment: I have solved my issue by running the second script with `lua_dofile` beforehand, this make all variables, tables and functions available to every other lua script in my program.